# Can't upload file

Tags: php, firefox, pdf, upload

I've made an CMS for a customer. One of the things he can do is upload a PDF file. We've tested this thoroughly and haven't encountered any bugs. However, he can't seem to upload anything at all. The file is never uploaded. His browser just keeps loading.

My client uses Firefox (not sure which version but I thought that wouldn't matter) and the PDF files he attempts to upload are around 5MB, nothing extreme.

Is there any reason why a browser doesn't finish it's request when uploading a file? I don't think the files are corrupt.

I don't think the problem lies in my script... but still worth posting:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['pdf'])) {
    $path = '../pdf/';
    $filename = $_FILES['pdf']['name'];

    if(!empty($assoc['pdf'])) {
        $oldfile = $path.$assoc['pdf'];

        if(file_exists($oldfile)) {
            unset($oldfile);
        }
    }

    $success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'], $path.$filename);
}
```

---

Edit: He has sent me the PDF he's trying to upload. Took about 10 seconds to upload... I'm providing him a link to do a speed test, lol.

Comment: What does the HTML form look like? Are you posting to an iframe, to a follow-up-page, to PHP_SELF, or via AJAX? Depending on how this is happening, it's possible that other processes are interrupting the upload. For instance, if you're uploading to an iframe and the target frame is redirected or reloaded during the upload, Firefox will just infinitely keep trying the post but never succeeds.

Comment: He/she likely just hasn't had time to try it and is biding his time by making up "it's not working" excuse. Seems to be the most common error we have! :)

Comment: have you added some prints in your code to make sure the file is truly being uploaded?  Is `$success` set to true or does the browser never respond?

Comment: @BenD The form is just an ordinary HTML form using a follow-up page to a semi-static URL (`?p=upload&id=<id goes here>`). If any of what you mentioned would be the error, it wouldn't work here I guess, but it does.
@Dave I've been thinking the same, but I slightly doubt that a 5MB PDF upload would take up to many minutes.

Comment: @Robert I use the `$success` variable to display whether the upload has succeeded or failed. In my question I clearly state that his browser keeps trying to load the next page.

Comment: Ok so have you tried removing the upload part to make sure that's where it's causing the problems?  How long has it sat on the loading screen?

Comment: @Robert I have. He's been stuck for a couple of minutes while it should be a matter of seconds, considering his upload speed.

Answer (score 1):

You can have two problems i see, might not be your exact problems but could lead you to your answer.

**#1. POST_MAX_SIZE or UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE is not big enough**

There are two configs that php programmers often forget about and this is probably your most obvious problem. Your tests have been done but have they been done with large files?

Using an htaccess or a php.ini (depending on your server configuration) you can override the php settings for

1. upload_max_filesize
2. post_max_size

And give them 20M for example:

```
/*.HTACCESS*/
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M

/*PHP.INI*/
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
```

You cannot use ini_set() because these variables are used BEFORE php starts processing and thus would become useless in the context.

**#2. enctype is not multipart/form-data**

Although very unprobable, you might have forgot to set your enctype property on your form to "multipart/form-data" and thus, nothing gets sent to the server at all. But i doubt this is your issue since you said you tested it extensively.

BUT, sometimes, we move things around and forget to test (it happens to me too) and i was sure something worked before and now it's not, so check it out just to make sure :)

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have to disappoint you. I did manage to find out that upload_max_filesize is a bit low (8mb) but still enough to upload the files he's trying to upload (6mb). Besides, if it was a server problem I wouldn't be able to upload the same files either while I stated I did manage to upload the files. Also, the enctype is correct.

Comment: @Tim S have you checked any network restrictions? maybe try a smaller file.

Answer (score 0):

Have the client try uploading the file in a different browser than Firefox. If it works in others browsers, try deleting (or renaming/moving, for testing purposes) the file [MimeTypes.rdf](http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf) in the client's [Firefox profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder).

If the PDF upload works afterwards, you encountered [a Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=373621#c59) that was first reported in 2007 ([basically the same here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=332690), reported in 2006). In a nutshell, any web site from which the user ever downloads a file has the potential to corrupt the MimeTypes.rdf file in regards to the extension of the downloaded file - maliciously or accidentally/unknowingly.

Things you can do:

1. [Vote for the Firefox bug!](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/page.cgi?id=voting/user.html&bug_id=373621#vote_373621)
2. Quick fix to get it working for the client right now: Have the user(s) delete their MimeTypes.rdf file. Firefox will create a new, "fresh" one at the next start, but this will clear all MIME type / application associations that the user has created over time. Also, this will only help until the user downloads the next PDF file from some other web site that corrupts the MimeTypes.rdf file again.
3. Use the "user agent" header to determine if the file is uploaded from Firefox. If so and the MIME type doesn't match anything you wish to accept, double-check the file name's extension and accept the file anyway if the extension matches your accepted file type(s) (".pdf" in your case).